# So, what issue i have is my camera is connected but its not showing when i do lsusb and I really don't get what is the issue

Tags: usb, camera

```
ase) caiedge@caiedge-Precision-3650-Tower:~$ dmesg | grep usb
[    0.819578] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.819578] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.819578] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    1.281267] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    1.281268] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.281269] usb usb1: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.281270] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 4.15.0-159-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.281270] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    1.282568] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003
[    1.282569] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.282570] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.282570] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 4.15.0-159-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.282571] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    1.283673] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    1.283674] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.283675] usb usb3: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.283676] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 4.15.0-159-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.283676] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:01:00.2
[    1.283886] usb usb4: We don't know the algorithms for LPM for this host, disabling LPM.
[    1.283896] usb usb4: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003
[    1.283897] usb usb4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.283898] usb usb4: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.283899] usb usb4: Manufacturer: Linux 4.15.0-159-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.283899] usb usb4: SerialNumber: 0000:01:00.2
[    1.500746] usb 2-8: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    1.524628] usb 2-8: New USB device found, idVendor=1e10, idProduct=4000
[    1.524628] usb 2-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    1.524629] usb 2-8: Product: Blackfly S BFS-U3-31S4C
[    1.524629] usb 2-8: Manufacturer: FLIR
[    1.524630] usb 2-8: SerialNumber: 013583DF
[    1.648565] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    1.801436] usb 1-6: New USB device found, idVendor=222a, idProduct=0001
[    1.801437] usb 1-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    1.801438] usb 1-6: Product: ILITEK-TP
[    1.801439] usb 1-6: Manufacturer: ILITEK
[    1.933275] usb 2-9: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    1.964892] usb 2-9: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=0328
[    1.964892] usb 2-9: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    1.964893] usb 2-9: Product: USB3.0-CRW
[    1.964893] usb 2-9: Manufacturer: Generic
[    1.964894] usb 2-9: SerialNumber: 28203008282014000
[    1.972554] usb-storage 2-9:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[    1.972791] scsi host4: usb-storage 2-9:1.0
[    1.972820] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    1.973837] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[    2.085170] usb 1-12: new full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    2.234667] usb 1-12: New USB device found, idVendor=067b, idProduct=2303
[    2.234669] usb 1-12: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    2.234670] usb 1-12: Product: USB-Serial Controller
[    2.234670] usb 1-12: Manufacturer: Prolific Technology Inc.
[    2.240310] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    2.240310] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    2.241748] input: ILITEK ILITEK-TP as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0/0003:222A:0001.0001/input/input3
[    2.241870] hid-generic 0003:222A:0001.0001: input,hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Device [ILITEK ILITEK-TP] on usb-0000:00:14.0-6/input0
[    2.836132] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[    2.836138] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
[    2.838702] usbcore: registered new interface driver pl2303
[    2.838713] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for pl2303
[    2.841824] usb 1-12: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[    2.890865] input: ILITEK ILITEK-TP as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0/0003:222A:0001.0001/input/input5
[    2.891218] hid-multitouch 0003:222A:0001.0001: input,hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Device [ILITEK ILITEK-TP] on usb-0000:00:14.0-6/input0
[   29.103560] usb 2-8: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  299.988261] usb 2-8: USB disconnect, device number 2
[  300.262238] usb 2-8: new SuperSpeed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[  300.284487] usb 2-8: New USB device found, idVendor=1e10, idProduct=4000
[  300.284488] usb 2-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  300.284489] usb 2-8: Product: Blackfly S BFS-U3-31S4C
[  300.284490] usb 2-8: Manufacturer: FLIR
[  300.284490] usb 2-8: SerialNumber: 013583DF
[  407.184475] usb 2-8: USB disconnect, device number 4
[  407.458500] usb 2-8: new SuperSpeed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[  407.480642] usb 2-8: New USB device found, idVendor=1e10, idProduct=4000
[  407.480643] usb 2-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  407.480643] usb 2-8: Product: Blackfly S BFS-U3-31S4C
[  407.480644] usb 2-8: Manufacturer: FLIR
[  407.480645] usb 2-8: SerialNumber: 013583DF
[  526.313004] usb 2-8: USB disconnect, device number 5
[  526.587018] usb 2-8: new SuperSpeed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[  526.609241] usb 2-8: New USB device found, idVendor=1e10, idProduct=4000
[  526.609242] usb 2-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  526.609243] usb 2-8: Product: Blackfly S BFS-U3-31S4C
[  526.609243] usb 2-8: Manufacturer: FLIR
[  526.609244] usb 2-8: SerialNumber: 013583DF
[  810.160154] usb 2-8: USB disconnect, device number 6
[  810.434216] usb 2-8: new SuperSpeed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[  810.456359] usb 2-8: New USB device found, idVendor=1e10, idProduct=4000
[  810.456359] usb 2-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  810.456360] usb 2-8: Product: Blackfly S BFS-U3-31S4C
[  810.456361] usb 2-8: Manufacturer: FLIR
[  810.456361] usb 2-8: SerialNumber: 013583DF
[ 2392.908715] usb 2-8: USB disconnect, device number 7
[ 2393.182766] usb 2-8: new SuperSpeed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[ 2393.205006] usb 2-8: New USB device found, idVendor=1e10, idProduct=4000
[ 2393.205007] usb 2-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 2393.205007] usb 2-8: Product: Blackfly S BFS-U3-31S4C
[ 2393.205008] usb 2-8: Manufacturer: FLIR
[ 2393.205009] usb 2-8: SerialNumber: 013583DF
[ 2607.582942] usb 2-8: USB disconnect, device number 8
[ 2609.434131] usb 1-12: USB disconnect, device number 3
[ 2716.228305] usb 2-8: new SuperSpeed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[ 2716.250272] usb 2-8: New USB device found, idVendor=1e10, idProduct=4000
[ 2716.250273] usb 2-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 2716.250273] usb 2-8: Product: Blackfly S BFS-U3-31S4C
[ 2716.250274] usb 2-8: Manufacturer: FLIR
[ 2716.250274] usb 2-8: SerialNumber: 013583DF
[ 2716.730002] usb 1-12: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[ 2716.879023] usb 1-12: New USB device found, idVendor=067b, idProduct=2303
[ 2716.879024] usb 1-12: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 2716.879024] usb 1-12: Product: USB-Serial Controller
[ 2716.879025] usb 1-12: Manufacturer: Prolific Technology Inc.
[ 2716.880653] usb 1-12: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[ 6999.447684] usb 2-8: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[ 7010.504877] usb 2-8: USB disconnect, device number 9
[ 7010.779336] usb 2-8: new SuperSpeed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[ 7010.801880] usb 2-8: New USB device found, idVendor=1e10, idProduct=4000
[ 7010.801885] usb 2-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 7010.801889] usb 2-8: Product: Blackfly S BFS-U3-31S4C
[ 7010.801892] usb 2-8: Manufacturer: FLIR
[ 7010.801894] usb 2-8: SerialNumber: 013583DF
[ 7083.900292] usb 2-8: USB disconnect, device number 10
[ 7084.178743] usb 2-8: new SuperSpeed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[ 7084.200766] usb 2-8: New USB device found, idVendor=1e10, idProduct=4000
[ 7084.200767] usb 2-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 7084.200768] usb 2-8: Product: Blackfly S BFS-U3-31S4C
[ 7084.200768] usb 2-8: Manufacturer: FLIR
[ 7084.200769] usb 2-8: SerialNumber: 013583DF
[ 7189.959643] usb 2-8: USB disconnect, device number 11
[ 7190.233980] usb 2-8: new SuperSpeed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[ 7190.256560] usb 2-8: New USB device found, idVendor=1e10, idProduct=4000
[ 7190.256566] usb 2-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 7190.256569] usb 2-8: Product: Blackfly S BFS-U3-31S4C
[ 7190.256572] usb 2-8: Manufacturer: FLIR
[ 7190.256575] usb 2-8: SerialNumber: 013583DF
[ 8883.061273] usb 2-8: USB disconnect, device number 12
[ 8883.335501] usb 2-8: new SuperSpeed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[ 8883.357562] usb 2-8: New USB device found, idVendor=1e10, idProduct=4000
[ 8883.357564] usb 2-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 8883.357564] usb 2-8: Product: Blackfly S BFS-U3-31S4C
[ 8883.357565] usb 2-8: Manufacturer: FLIR
[ 8883.357566] usb 2-8: SerialNumber: 013583DF
[13987.921869] usb 2-8: USB disconnect, device number 13
[13988.196320] usb 2-8: new SuperSpeed USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
[13988.222265] usb 2-8: New USB device found, idVendor=1e10, idProduct=4000
[13988.222269] usb 2-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[13988.222273] usb 2-8: Product: Blackfly S BFS-U3-31S4C
[13988.222276] usb 2-8: Manufacturer: FLIR
[13988.222279] usb 2-8: SerialNumber: 013583DF
[14456.146144] usb 2-8: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
[14629.991318] usb 2-8: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
[15451.775720] usb 2-8: USB disconnect, device number 14
[15452.053758] usb 2-8: new SuperSpeed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
[15452.075867] usb 2-8: New USB device found, idVendor=1e10, idProduct=4000
[15452.075868] usb 2-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[15452.075869] usb 2-8: Product: Blackfly S BFS-U3-31S4C
[15452.075870] usb 2-8: Manufacturer: FLIR
[15452.075870] usb 2-8: SerialNumber: 013583DF
[17171.002722] usb 2-8: USB disconnect, device number 15
[17171.276696] usb 2-8: new SuperSpeed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
[17171.298935] usb 2-8: New USB device found, idVendor=1e10, idProduct=4000
[17171.298936] usb 2-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[17171.298936] usb 2-8: Product: Blackfly S BFS-U3-31S4C
[17171.298937] usb 2-8: Manufacturer: FLIR
[17171.298938] usb 2-8: SerialNumber: 013583DF
[22350.536710] usb 2-8: USB disconnect, device number 16
[22350.810695] usb 2-8: new SuperSpeed USB device number 17 using xhci_hcd
[22350.832885] usb 2-8: New USB device found, idVendor=1e10, idProduct=4000
[22350.832886] usb 2-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[22350.832887] usb 2-8: Product: Blackfly S BFS-U3-31S4C
[22350.832887] usb 2-8: Manufacturer: FLIR
[22350.832888] usb 2-8: SerialNumber: 013583DF
[24886.120299] usb 2-8: USB disconnect, device number 17
[24886.394404] usb 2-8: new SuperSpeed USB device number 18 using xhci_hcd
[24886.416493] usb 2-8: New USB device found, idVendor=1e10, idProduct=4000
[24886.416494] usb 2-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[24886.416495] usb 2-8: Product: Blackfly S BFS-U3-31S4C
[24886.416496] usb 2-8: Manufacturer: FLIR
[24886.416497] usb 2-8: SerialNumber: 013583DF
[49344.637830] usb 2-8: USB disconnect, device number 18
[49344.911795] usb 2-8: new SuperSpeed USB device number 19 using xhci_hcd
[49344.934013] usb 2-8: New USB device found, idVendor=1e10, idProduct=4000
[49344.934014] usb 2-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[49344.934015] usb 2-8: Product: Blackfly S BFS-U3-31S4C
[49344.934016] usb 2-8: Manufacturer: FLIR
[49344.934016] usb 2-8: SerialNumber: 013583DF
[75648.212296] usb 2-8: USB disconnect, device number 19
[75648.486301] usb 2-8: new SuperSpeed USB device number 20 using xhci_hcd
[75648.508414] usb 2-8: New USB device found, idVendor=1e10, idProduct=4000
[75648.508416] usb 2-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[75648.508417] usb 2-8: Product: Blackfly S BFS-U3-31S4C
[75648.508418] usb 2-8: Manufacturer: FLIR
[75648.508419] usb 2-8: SerialNumber: 013583DF
[77438.202187] usb 2-8: USB disconnect, device number 20
[77438.476201] usb 2-8: new SuperSpeed USB device number 21 using xhci_hcd
[77438.498322] usb 2-8: New USB device found, idVendor=1e10, idProduct=4000
[77438.498324] usb 2-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[77438.498325] usb 2-8: Product: Blackfly S BFS-U3-31S4C
[77438.498326] usb 2-8: Manufacturer: FLIR
[77438.498327] usb 2-8: SerialNumber: 013583DF
[81706.114850] usb 2-8: USB disconnect, device number 21
[81706.388933] usb 2-8: new SuperSpeed USB device number 22 using xhci_hcd
[81706.411060] usb 2-8: New USB device found, idVendor=1e10, idProduct=4000
[81706.411061] usb 2-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[81706.411062] usb 2-8: Product: Blackfly S BFS-U3-31S4C
[81706.411062] usb 2-8: Manufacturer: FLIR
[81706.411063] usb 2-8: SerialNumber: 013583DF
[82633.251237] usb 2-8: USB disconnect, device number 22
[82633.525284] usb 2-8: new SuperSpeed USB device number 23 using xhci_hcd
[82633.547412] usb 2-8: New USB device found, idVendor=1e10, idProduct=4000
[82633.547414] usb 2-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[82633.547415] usb 2-8: Product: Blackfly S BFS-U3-31S4C
[82633.547416] usb 2-8: Manufacturer: FLIR
[82633.547417] usb 2-8: SerialNumber: 013583DF
[83544.136488] usb 2-8: USB disconnect, device number 23
[83544.410545] usb 2-8: new SuperSpeed USB device number 24 using xhci_hcd
[83544.432636] usb 2-8: New USB device found, idVendor=1e10, idProduct=4000
[83544.432637] usb 2-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[83544.432638] usb 2-8: Product: Blackfly S BFS-U3-31S4C
[83544.432639] usb 2-8: Manufacturer: FLIR
[83544.432639] usb 2-8: SerialNumber: 013583DF
[85226.059206] usb 2-8: USB disconnect, device number 24
[85226.333254] usb 2-8: new SuperSpeed USB device number 25 using xhci_hcd
[85226.355370] usb 2-8: New USB device found, idVendor=1e10, idProduct=4000
[85226.355372] usb 2-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[85226.355373] usb 2-8: Product: Blackfly S BFS-U3-31S4C
[85226.355374] usb 2-8: Manufacturer: FLIR
[85226.355375] usb 2-8: SerialNumber: 013583DF
[87082.402988] usb 2-8: USB disconnect, device number 25
[87082.677014] usb 2-8: new SuperSpeed USB device number 26 using xhci_hcd
[87082.699139] usb 2-8: New USB device found, idVendor=1e10, idProduct=4000
[87082.699141] usb 2-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[87082.699142] usb 2-8: Product: Blackfly S BFS-U3-31S4C
[87082.699143] usb 2-8: Manufacturer: FLIR
[87082.699144] usb 2-8: SerialNumber: 013583DF
[89004.566479] usb 2-8: USB disconnect, device number 26
[89004.840509] usb 2-8: new SuperSpeed USB device number 27 using xhci_hcd
[89004.862739] usb 2-8: New USB device found, idVendor=1e10, idProduct=4000
[89004.862740] usb 2-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[89004.862741] usb 2-8: Product: Blackfly S BFS-U3-31S4C
[89004.862741] usb 2-8: Manufacturer: FLIR
[89004.862742] usb 2-8: SerialNumber: 013583DF
[91427.855662] usb 2-8: USB disconnect, device number 27
[91428.129657] usb 2-8: new SuperSpeed USB device number 28 using xhci_hcd
[91428.151845] usb 2-8: New USB device found, idVendor=1e10, idProduct=4000
[91428.151846] usb 2-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[91428.151847] usb 2-8: Product: Blackfly S BFS-U3-31S4C
[91428.151848] usb 2-8: Manufacturer: FLIR
[91428.151848] usb 2-8: SerialNumber: 013583DF
[95509.935893] usb 2-8: USB disconnect, device number 28
[95510.209967] usb 2-8: new SuperSpeed USB device number 29 using xhci_hcd
[95510.232046] usb 2-8: New USB device found, idVendor=1e10, idProduct=4000
[95510.232047] usb 2-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[95510.232048] usb 2-8: Product: Blackfly S BFS-U3-31S4C
[95510.232049] usb 2-8: Manufacturer: FLIR
[95510.232049] usb 2-8: SerialNumber: 013583DF
[96566.936590] usb 2-8: USB disconnect, device number 29
[96567.210712] usb 2-8: new SuperSpeed USB device number 30 using xhci_hcd
[96567.232824] usb 2-8: New USB device found, idVendor=1e10, idProduct=4000
[96567.232825] usb 2-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[96567.232825] usb 2-8: Product: Blackfly S BFS-U3-31S4C
[96567.232826] usb 2-8: Manufacturer: FLIR
[96567.232827] usb 2-8: SerialNumber: 013583DF
[97892.021438] usb 2-8: USB disconnect, device number 30
[97892.295449] usb 2-8: new SuperSpeed USB device number 31 using xhci_hcd
[97892.317565] usb 2-8: New USB device found, idVendor=1e10, idProduct=4000
[97892.317567] usb 2-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[97892.317568] usb 2-8: Product: Blackfly S BFS-U3-31S4C
[97892.317569] usb 2-8: Manufacturer: FLIR
[97892.317570] usb 2-8: SerialNumber: 013583DF
[99804.304035] usb 2-8: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 31 using xhci_hcd
[99858.897052] usb 2-8: USB disconnect, device number 31
[99859.171074] usb 2-8: new SuperSpeed USB device number 32 using xhci_hcd
[99859.193217] usb 2-8: New USB device found, idVendor=1e10, idProduct=4000
[99859.193219] usb 2-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[99859.193220] usb 2-8: Product: Blackfly S BFS-U3-31S4C
[99859.193221] usb 2-8: Manufacturer: FLIR
[99859.193222] usb 2-8: SerialNumber: 013583DF
[100088.408306] usb 2-8: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 32 using xhci_hcd
[100125.423709] usb 2-8: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 32 using xhci_hcd
[101079.580437] usb 2-8: USB disconnect, device number 32
[101079.854466] usb 2-8: new SuperSpeed USB device number 33 using xhci_hcd
[101079.876588] usb 2-8: New USB device found, idVendor=1e10, idProduct=4000
[101079.876590] usb 2-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[101079.876591] usb 2-8: Product: Blackfly S BFS-U3-31S4C
[101079.876592] usb 2-8: Manufacturer: FLIR
[101079.876593] usb 2-8: SerialNumber: 013583DF
[107558.960830] usb 2-8: USB disconnect, device number 33
[107559.234873] usb 2-8: new SuperSpeed USB device number 34 using xhci_hcd
[107559.256963] usb 2-8: New USB device found, idVendor=1e10, idProduct=4000
[107559.256964] usb 2-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[107559.256965] usb 2-8: Product: Blackfly S BFS-U3-31S4C
[107559.256966] usb 2-8: Manufacturer: FLIR
[107559.256966] usb 2-8: SerialNumber: 013583DF
[108059.685539] usb 2-8: USB disconnect, device number 34
[108059.959532] usb 2-8: new SuperSpeed USB device number 35 using xhci_hcd
[108059.981660] usb 2-8: New USB device found, idVendor=1e10, idProduct=4000
[108059.981662] usb 2-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[108059.981663] usb 2-8: Product: Blackfly S BFS-U3-31S4C
[108059.981664] usb 2-8: Manufacturer: FLIR
[108059.981665] usb 2-8: SerialNumber: 013583DF
[109035.981516] usb 2-8: USB disconnect, device number 35
[109036.255478] usb 2-8: new SuperSpeed USB device number 36 using xhci_hcd
[109036.277706] usb 2-8: New USB device found, idVendor=1e10, idProduct=4000
[109036.277708] usb 2-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[109036.277709] usb 2-8: Product: Blackfly S BFS-U3-31S4C
[109036.277710] usb 2-8: Manufacturer: FLIR
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us some context. Start from the beginning: what operating system are you using? If Linux, which one? What camera is this? How are you connecting it? Do you use a USB hub? Is this a laptop? A Desktop? Do other USB devices work? Next, please ask the question as part of the question instead of a really long title. The title should just be a description, something short so we can have an idea of what the question is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.